# Blender seems to extend invisible keyframes in the animation timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm trying to do a simple idle animation...I click on frame 1, insert location/rotation.  Everything seems fine.  I move to the next frame...say 10 frames ahead and move the hips down slightly.  Auto key frame is added...but when I scrub, I can see that the position I just set doesn't actually end up in that location until another 10 or so frames.

I have middle clicked down to scroll the frames down, I have clicked the home button while in the timeline but Blender won't end the animation on the current keyframe.  Instead it extends it beyond where there are any keyframes and I can't see them to re adjust them.

I've even tried multiple versions of Blender but it keeps doing the same thing.  I'm sure it's me doing something dumb but I can't figure it out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OMG...I had "Time Remapping" enabled.  I had it set from 100 frames to 250 frames.  Guess I don't know how to properly do a loop.